# How to inject an Activity into an Adapter using dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8

I am trying to inject my MainActivity into my Adapter. However, my solution works ok, but I think its a code smell and not the right way to do it.

My adapter snippet looks like this the but I don't like about this is that I have to cast the `Activity` to `MainActivity`:

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListViewHolder> {
    private List<Recipe> recipeList = Collections.emptyList();
    private Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public RecipeAdapter(Activity activity, Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
        this.recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.viewHolderFactories = viewHolderFactories;
        this.mainActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        /* Inject the viewholder */
        final RecipeListViewHolder recipeListViewHolder = viewHolderFactories.get(Constants.RECIPE_LIST).createViewHolder(viewGroup);

        recipeListViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /* Using the MainActivity to call a callback listener */
                mainActivity.onRecipeItemClick(getRecipe(recipeListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });

        return recipeListViewHolder;
    }
}
```

In my Module, I pass the Activity in the module's constructor and pass it to the Adapter.

```
@Module
public class RecipeListModule {
    private Activity activity;

    public RecipeListModule() {}

    public RecipeListModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @RecipeListScope
    @Provides
    RecipeAdapter providesRecipeAdapter(Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
        return new RecipeAdapter(activity, viewHolderFactories);
    }
}
```

In My Application class I create the components and I am using a SubComponent for the adapter. Here I have to pass the Activity which I am not sure is a good idea.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    applicationComponent = createApplicationComponent();
    recipeListComponent = createRecipeListComponent();
}

public BusbyBakingComponent createApplicationComponent() {
    return DaggerBusbyBakingComponent.builder()
            .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
            .androidModule(new AndroidModule(BusbyBakingApplication.this))
            .exoPlayerModule(new ExoPlayerModule())
            .build();
}

public RecipeListComponent createRecipeListComponent(Activity activity) {
    return recipeListComponent = applicationComponent.add(new RecipeListModule(activity));
}
```

My Fragment I inject like this:

```
@Inject RecipeAdapter recipeAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((BusbyBakingApplication)getActivity().getApplication())
                .createRecipeListComponent(getActivity())
                .inject(this);
    }
```

Even though the above design works, I think it's a code smell as I have to cast the Activity to the MainActivity. The reason I use the Activity as I want to make this module more generic.

Just wondering if there is a better way

=============== UPDATE USING INTERFACE

Interface

```
public interface RecipeItemClickListener {
    void onRecipeItemClick(Recipe recipe);
}
```

Implementation

```
public class RecipeItemClickListenerImp implements RecipeItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onRecipeItemClick(Recipe recipe, Context context) {
        final Intent intent = Henson.with(context)
                .gotoRecipeDetailActivity()
                .recipe(recipe)
                .build();

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In my module, I have the following providers

```
@Module
public class RecipeListModule {
    @RecipeListScope
    @Provides
    RecipeItemClickListener providesRecipeItemClickListenerImp() {
        return new RecipeItemClickListenerImp();
    }

    @RecipeListScope
    @Provides
    RecipeAdapter providesRecipeAdapter(RecipeItemClickListener recipeItemClickListener, Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
        return new RecipeAdapter(recipeItemClickListener, viewHolderFactories);
    }
}
```

Then I use it through constructor injection in the RecipeAdapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListViewHolder> {
    private List<Recipe> recipeList = Collections.emptyList();
    private Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories;
    private RecipeItemClickListener recipeItemClickListener;

    @Inject /* IS THIS NESSESSARY - AS IT WORKS WITH AND WITHOUT THE @Inject annotation */
    public RecipeAdapter(RecipeItemClickListener recipeItemClickListener, Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
        this.recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.viewHolderFactories = viewHolderFactories;
        this.recipeItemClickListener = recipeItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        /* Inject the viewholder */
        final RecipeListViewHolder recipeListViewHolder = viewHolderFactories.get(Constants.RECIPE_LIST).createViewHolder(viewGroup);

        recipeListViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recipeItemClickListener.onRecipeItemClick(getRecipe(recipeListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()), viewGroup.getContext());
            }
        });

        return recipeListViewHolder;
    }
}
```

Just one question, is the @Inject annotation need for the constructor in the RecipeAdapter. As it works with or without the @Inject.

Comment: Please have a look at Constructor Injection and how to use it. Creating `provides*` methods that only call a constructor are nothing but noise and code to maintain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need a `MainActivity` then you should also provide it. Instead of `Activity` declare `MainActivity` for your module.

```
@Module
public class RecipeListModule {
  private MainActivity activity;

  public RecipeListModule(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }
}
```

And your Adapter should just request it (Constructor Injection for *non* Android Framework types!)

```
@RecipeListScope
class RecipeAdapter {

  @Inject
  RecipeAdapter(MainActivity activity,
          Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
    // ...
  }

}
```

---

If you want your module to use `Activity` and not `MainActivity` then you will need to declare an interface as already mentioned. You adapter would then declare the interface as its dependency.

But in some module you will still have to bind that interface to your `MainActivity` and one module needs to know how to provide the dependency.

```
// in some abstract module
@Binds MyAdapterInterface(MainActivity activity) // bind the activity to the interface
```

---

**Addressing the updated part of the question**

> Just one question, is the `@Inject` annotation need for the constructor in the RecipeAdapter. As it works with or without the `@Inject`.

It works without it because you're still not using constructor injection. You're still calling the constructor *yourself* in `providesRecipeAdapter()`. As a general rule of thumb—if you want to use Dagger properly—don't ever call `new` yourself. If you want to use `new` ask yourself if you could be using constructor injection instead.

The same module you show could be written as follows, making use of `@Binds` to bind an implementation to the interface, and actually using constructor injection to create the adapter (which is why we don't have to write any method for it! Less code to maintain, less errors, more readable classes)

As you see I don't need to use `new` myself—Dagger will create the objects for me.

```
public abstract class RecipeListModule {
  @RecipeListScope
  @Binds
  RecipeItemClickListener providesRecipeClickListener(RecipeItemClickListenerImp listener);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Do not pass Activities into Adapters - This is a really bad practice.

Inject only the fields you care about.

In your example: Pass an interface into the adapter to track the item click.

Comment: mrsegev using interfaces as specified in your answer. I have updated my question with my solution that uses interface. Just wondering is the @Inject annotation needed for the constructor?

Comment: I hope I understand your question - If you want the dependencies to be injected use the @Inject annoatation.

Comment: Without the @Inject annotation, Dagger won't use the objects graph to satisfy the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do the following trick

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "__ACTIVITY__";

    public static MainActivity get(Context context) {
        // noinspection ResourceType
        return (MainActivity)context.getSystemService(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getSystemService(String name) {
        if(TAG.equals(name)) {
            return this;
        }
        return super.getSystemService(name);
    }
}

public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListViewHolder> {
    private List<Recipe> recipeList = Collections.emptyList();
    private Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories;

    public RecipeAdapter(Map<Integer, RecipeListViewHolderFactory> viewHolderFactories) {
        this.recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.viewHolderFactories = viewHolderFactories;
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        /* Inject the viewholder */
        final RecipeListViewHolder recipeListViewHolder = viewHolderFactories.get(Constants.RECIPE_LIST).createViewHolder(viewGroup);

        recipeListViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = MainActivity.get(v.getContext());
                if(recipeListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() != -1) {
                    mainActivity.onRecipeItemClick(
                      getRecipe(recipeListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            }
        });

        return recipeListViewHolder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think its more of a hack, and maybe not testable.

Comment: You can also pass interfaces

Comment: I have updated my question to use interface instead. Please take a look if you think there is any off.